# Для того, чтобы

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложении?

> Мария, читавшая рядом с камином, отложила свой томик поэзии, для того,
> чтобы тоже услышать продолжение истории от Ивана.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложении? **Одна из запятых лишняя.** Это тема расчленения  составного союза ДЛЯ ТОГО ЧТОБЫ, где возможны **два варианта** оформления:

(1) *Мария, читавшая рядом с камИном, //**отложила свой томик поэзии для тогО**, // чтобы тоже услышать продолжение истории от Ивана.*

(2) *Мария, читавшая рядом с камИном, // **отложила свой томик поЭзии,** // для того чтобы тоже услышать продолжение истории от Ивана.*

2. **Но как сделать выбор?**   При заданной структуре предложения желательно ВЫБРАТЬ **первый вариант**, который более удобен для прочтения. В этом случае  интонационно мы делим предложение  на три примерно **равные** по объему части.
3. С точки зрения **семантики**, если ударение падает на указательное слово, как в первом случае, то придаточной части придается **большая значимость.**

Материал ответа изложен в соответствии с правилом Розенталя  § 34. Запятая при сложных подчинительных союзах http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

Там указано, что расчленение союза зависит от **смысла, интонации, логического подчеркивания** придаточной части и других факторов.

Comment: Уважаемые участники! Еще раз призываю всех отмечать вопрос, на который вы отвечаете. Если вы беретесь за него, появляется возможность еще раз освежить в памяти свои знания, углубить их, открыть новые аспекты и пр., и, в конце концов, получить за это баллы.

Comment: А мне мой вопрос тоже отметили, правда минусовкой. И стали на него отвечать.

Answer (score 2):

*«Мария, читавшая рядом с камином, отложила свой томик поэзии, **для того чтобы** тоже услышать продолжение истории от Ивана».*

В данном случае союз «для того чтобы» полностью входит в придаточную часть и не разделятся запятой.

Например:

*Я упросил моих учителей (все через Упадышевского), чтобы мне задавали не по одному, а по два и по три урока, **для того чтобы** догнать старших учеников и не сидеть на одной лавке с новенькими.*
Аксаков С. Т., Воспоминания

---

Однако, если вы хотите указать, что логическое ударение падает на первую часть союза, то возможно написание:

---

*«Мария, читавшая рядом с камином, отложила свой томик поэзии **для того**, чтобы тоже услышать продолжение истории от Ивана».*

*Отложила именно **для того**, чтобы тоже услышать продолжение истории от Ивана.*

---

Например:

*“В 1817 году он оставил Нью-Лэнэрк **для того, чтобы** искать себе более обширный круг деятельности”*.
Добролюбов Н. А., Роберт Овэн и его попытки общественных реформ

*Он оставил Нью-Лэнэрк имеено **для того**, чтобы искать себе более обширный круг деятельности.*

---

Вот правило, касательно последнего варианта написания:

> **Составной подчинительный союз расчленяется** и запятая ставится между
> частями союза, если выполняется хотя бы одно из следующих условий:
> …
>
> - автор желает подчеркнуть, что на первую часть составного союза падает    логическое ударение:
>
> *Мужики тихи, робки и вежливы **оттого, что** у каждого для весу в кудели по камню…* М. Пришвин, Мирская чаша. *Я спросил у отца, что
> значит «особенный вечер». Отец объяснил мне, что этот вечер называется
> так **потому, что** он не похож на все остальные.* К. Паустовский,
> Сказочник.
>
> [[gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3)]

---

При ответе на вопрос я использовал правила из [Пунктуация в конструкциях с составными подчинительными союзами](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3) и [Для того(,) чтобы, *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_172) с сайта [gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/).

Если нужно больше информации рекомендую почитать там, так как правило объёмное и цитирование замёт слишком много места.

Comment: Выбор неясен.  Дается ОБЩЕЕ решение и описание двух вариантов, но автору текста или обычному пользователю нужен КОНКРЕТНЫЙ ВЫБОР и  более понятные ориентиры, чем подчеркивание логического ударения.  Следует указать один из вариантов как более предпочтительный и обосновать его преимущество без использования специальной терминологии, иначе задача не имеет конкретного решения.

Comment: Уважаемые участники! Еще раз призываю всех отмечать вопрос, на который вы отвечаете. Если вы беретесь за него, появляется возможность еще раз освежить в памяти свои знания, углубить их, открыть новые аспекты и пр., и, в конце концов, получить за это баллы.